# JFrog Xray integration with existing instance of Artifactory

Tags: devops, artifactory, jfrog-xray, devsecops

Artifactory instance up and running and in use on Windows 2012R2 (Server A), Is it possible to link this(Artifactory) with new Xray installation on a Linux server (Server B) ? any steps available in the existing documentation to do this ? Please suggest.

Note: Xray installation is rpm on RHEL, not Docker.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the relevant documentation to install Xray [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Xray#InstallingXray-SingleNodeInstallation).
It's mostly around configuring the system.yaml, providing JFrog URL and a Join key from the Artifactory instance.
You might require a few more additional steps depending on the setup of the Artifactory instance (e.g - importing certificates in case of SSL).